# Are there mongoose performance benefits to update vs findByIdAndUpdate

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to update basic CRUD style with a REST api via a put operation. I have a coffeescript base class, where @model is a mongoose Model like *mongoose.model('Company', schema)* in a child class. I'm throwing around two ways of doing the PUT/update:

```
und = require 'underscore'

class CRUDApi

  # using findByIdAndUpdate
  update1: (req, res) =>
    data = und.clone req.body
    delete data._id # so mongo doesn't complain
    @model.findByIdAndUpdate req.params.id, data, (e, r) ->
      res.send r

  # using update
  update2: (req, res) =>
    data = und.clone req.body
    delete data._id # so mongo doesn't complain
    @model.update { _id: req.params.id }, data, (e, r) ->
      res.send req.body
```

My questions are:

1) Is there any performance difference between update & findByIdAndUpdate? findByIdAndUpdate seems like a better choice for syntax, especially because it returns the result in 'r' vs just the increment count, which feels better than 'faking' the response with req.body in update2()

2) Also it seems so awkward to clone the request and remove the _.id property just so mongoose doesn't complain. Is this the normal approach?

Answer (score 4):

1) There are performance benefits to using a mongoose's `findByXAndUpdate()` if you want to get back the document that was updated.  Underneath, it uses mongo's [findAndModify](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#findandmodify) method, which has an option to return the updated document after the update.  The alternative is to do a `find()` after the update to get the document.  It's probably not a good practice to return the posted body, as it shouldn't be trusted since it's from the user, and it wouldn't account for return complete documents where partial updates are allowed.

2) It is definitely a good practice to filter the incoming data from req.body to just the fields you're expecting, especially since you're passing them right into the model's update function.  Stripping off _id seems appropriate.